# MYSQL request values from single column after matching again user_id

Tags: mysql

I have just started to work a bit more with MySQL and Wordpress so any help would be most appreciated.

I have a table entry that looks like this.

```
 |-----meta_value-----||field_id||item_id|
 |---------45---------||---9----||---7---|
 |--------adam--------||---8----||---7---|
 |---------3----------||---13---||---7---|
 |---steve@test.com---||---14---||---7---|
 |------exercise------||---10---||---7---|
 |---------40---------||---9----||---6---|
 |--------steve-------||---8----||---6---|
 |---------1----------||---13---||---6---|
 |---adam@test.com----||---14---||---6---|
 |------Training------||---10---||---6---|
```

What I am aiming to do is extra the data ready to be used via graphing or tabling to end users.

I have the users email from when the login, which I am wanting to match against the meta_value before returning results that only match that person.

Once I have matched the username against the user_id from another table, I am then wanting to return the numerical values (field_id 9 and 13).

I have tried using joins and multiple select queries, alas they all return 0 rows.

I appreciate any help or advice that you are able to provide.

Many thanks,

Example SQL code

First

```
SELECT
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id = 9) AS Time,
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_frm_item_metas WHERE field_id = 13) AS Intensity
```

This did work when I had a single set of values, however it broke when a second entry was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Below query will give you desired output 

select item_id,sum(case when field_id=9 then meta_value else 0 end) Minutes, sum(case when field_id=13 then meta_value else 0 end) Intensity from ( 
select t.item_id,wpm.field_id,meta_value from (
SELECT item_id from wp_frm_item_metas where meta_value = 'richard@test.com' and field_id = 14) as t join wp_frm_item_metas wpm on t.item_id = wpm.item_id and wpm.field_id in (9,13) 
) as t1 group by item_id
```